# Convert Views to Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I created some views in visual studio by clicking right click=> add => view.
I select in the selection: "use a layout or master page".
Now I want to turn these views to partial views should I delete it and create new? or I can somehow turning it to partial view without deleting the views?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Razor there is no much difference in `View` and `partial view` 
Only difference is

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If there is no layout specified they could be considered as partial views.

From your controller action you return PartialView(); instead of return View(); this layout will not be applied.

Comment: so in order to convert my view to partial view I delete the Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; and then it is partial view that it?

Comment: should I also delete the ViewBag.Title="someTitle" or it can stay in partial views?

Comment: you can remove that...since you are using it as `partial` you wont require `Title`

Comment: Really useful stuff. I went to controller and in every return that had a View changed it to PartialView is that ok?