# Foreach not working when partial view is being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233988/convert-views-to-partial-views) i went to my code and changed my view to partial making all the returns that would return views to be returning partial views instead.
Then I called my partial view in a page, surprisingly enough when i call my partial view it outputs an error: "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**." [See this for details](https://imagebin.ca/v/3HEy1BjXwvkl) 
Thing is my partial view works just fine when I test it it just doesn't load when it is used in another page. What is the problem here?

Partial view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovieClean.Models.MovieClean>

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div class="album">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">



            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="card">
                    <img alt="100%x280" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImgURL)"/>
                    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Plot)</p>
                </div>

            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I am calling the partial view in the page:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml")
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have not passed model object to it and it will ofcourse fail as it will be null, if you have action in controller for this partial view, i would suggest to call it using `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` like:

### Possible Solution 1:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.Action("Index","Movies")
</div>
```

If you already have `MoviesController` class and in that you will see an action method named `Index`, `Html.Action("Index","Movies")` will call the Index method of `MoviesController` class and will render the returned html of the partial view as response in browser.

and your action would contain the code to get the movies from database and return in the partial view like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   var movies = ...// call to db to get them

  return PartialView("~/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml",movies);
}
```

### Possible Solution 2:

of if you have the movies collection in the model of you parent view, then you need to pass it to the partial view like:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml",Model.Movies)
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the lack of knowledge, but in your last block of code i can't seem to be able to use Model.Movies. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: as i said, if you have `Movies` property in your parent view model , in that case you can use this approach, other use `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction`

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly, can i just ask what exactly is @Html.Action("Index","Movies")  ? I get what the action is but where does "Index" and "Movies" come from?

Comment: in Controllers, you have `MoviesController` class and in that you will see an action method named `Index`, `Html.Action("Index","Movies")` will call the Index method of Movies controller and will render the returned html of the partial view as response in browser

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that you are not passing the model into your partial view.

you should be passing in something like:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Movies/Index.cshtml", model)
</div>
```

where model is an instance of

```
IEnumerable<MvcMovieClean.Models.MovieClean>
```

Comment: @model IEnumerable<MvcMovieClean.Models.MovieClean> is this the right way to instantiate?

Comment: yeah that would work, but if your model was more complex you'd have that IEnumerable as a property and whatever other properties you'd need for your partial view